# Для чего нужен exclude файл?

Tags: git

Не понимаю для чего нужен этот файл, не могли бы объяснить?

Comment: Где вы его нашли? Может `.gitignore`?

Comment: exclude или `.gitignore`?

Comment: Можно вручную подправить игнорирование файлов. Всё написано там ин инглиш.

Comment: Он в папке .git/info/ .

@AlexGlebe Подавить вручную игнориворание? Т.е. если у меня в **.gitignore** есть какой-то файл, то указав его в exclude, я перестану его игнорировать? Но там речь идёт о каких-то exclude patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл `.gitignore` - содержит в себе список файлов, которые не нужно отслеживать и напоминать, что вы за ними не следите. Если вы сделаете этот файл в каком-нибудь месте проекта, то не будет git напоминать вам об этом про все файлы в этой директории и внутри неё в других директориях рекурсивно.

Пример :

.gitignore :

```
*.o
*.a
temp/   # всё что в папке игнорируется
.*
*~
```

Файл `.git/info/exclude` делает то-же самое, что и `.gitignore` в корневой директории проекта.

Подправлять `.git/info/exclude` вместо `.gitignore` имеет смысл, если проект голый ( `--bare` ) на сервере.

Comment: Допустим, я использую:git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard
Для чего тут указывать exclude?

Comment: Когда вы хотите посмотреть игнорируемые файлы вы должны указать где исключения хранятся. `--exclude-stadnard` - ищет в стандартных местах, как мы говорили. А можно и в других местах хранить список исключений с помощью `--exclude-from=...`.

Comment: Понял, огромное спасибо.